# Android warning when open: keyBoard, editText and seekBar in one screen

Tags: android, keyboard

In one screen i have editText and seekBar, they sinhroniziroany together, that is seekBar change value, in edit text change value too and conversely. (I use TextWatcher and OnSeekBarChangeListener).
When keyboard hidden all work good, but when keyboard evidently and i change value, i have Warning in LogCat (All message):

```
05-22 15:28:36.423: W/SubtypeSwitcher(1783): Current subtype: en_US, keyboard
05-22 15:28:36.423: W/SubtypeSwitcher(1783): Last subtype was disabled. Update to the current one.
05-22 15:28:36.433: W/AbstractCompatWrapper(1783): Invalid input to AbstructCompatWrapper
05-22 15:28:36.433: W/CompatUtils(1783): Exception in invoke: NullPointerException
05-22 15:28:36.433: W/SubtypeSwitcher(1783): Update subtype to:en_US,keyboard, from: en_US, keyboard
```

How i can fix it?